# What is the up-to-date approach to handling multiple conflicts during rebase?

Tags: git, gitlab

Our team uses a more or less standard approach to development. We have our `master` branch that is used as the source for deployments.

Several backend developers all work on their feature branches and it happens pretty often that the master branch gets changed a lot as compared to the one used during the creation of the feature branch.

Usually, we don't care a lot about rebasing and merging locally so we just use the buttons kindly offered on Gitlab, which makes it a matter of one click to rebase master and then merge.

There is one case, though, when everything gets much more challenging. When Gitlab is unable to do everything automatically, it asks to rebase locally and then when you have a set of commits, you have to resolve the same conflict over and over again. Especially when you edited the same line a few times in several commits.

I have several options in mind, but I would like to also hear some advice.

1. Use merge instead and deal with conflicts only once
   In fact, this is what we do most often, just in the auto mode on Gitlab
2. Do `git pull origin master` and then `git rebase -i master` often enough so as not to get a mess once you decide you are ready to merge into master.
   This is also a convenient way to organize your commits in a timely manner
3. Use `git rerere` which memorizes the ways to resolve conflicts so that you don't have to redo them for every commit. I have never used this approach, but it seems, based on the description, that it might not work if you have minor edits of the same line in different commits.
4. Do something else. I might not be familiar with all the changes in Git so there could be some tool or procedure to simplify the workflow

Please, don't consider that question to be vague or opinion-based. I believe there are still correct ways to handle the situation and wrong approaches that can mess up your repository.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you have right there the best approaches. Depending on how messy my feature branch is and how many times a section of code is giving me conflicts when I rebase, I might op out for stopping rebase and try approach 1 (and then squashing it, I see no point in keeping the separate revisions if I will end up with a non-straight feature branch in the end).

Comment: @eftshift0, you mean `git merge --squash feature_branch && git commit`? So that you have just one commit message. 
If I understand correctly, there is no way to manually select what to squash into one commit without rebasing. Too bad, rebasing can be such a pain

Comment: I like to get my hands dirty so, in my case, after the merge (a normal merge) is finished/committed: `git reset --soft the-base-branch; git commit -m "Feature X"`